# how to convert php existing web application to mobile application

Tags: php, joomla1.5

i have developed a webpage with joomla 1.5, now i need to convert my web application to mobile application. the user can download my application through mobile apple or etc then they can access. Tell any tips and kindly guide me...

Comment: It depends on which devices you want your application.

Comment: If you are looking to create a mobile application, rather than just optimise a web site for mobile use, there are plenty of web resources for this. As per the answers, the correct response is "it depends what you are trying to do". If you are wanting to develop for the iPhone, download XCode, and search for tutorials; if you wish to target Android, download their SDK and search for tutorials. Plenty of self-directed research is necessary, I'm afraid!

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at phonegap ( http://phonegap.com/ ) 
It is a java framework that you can control with javascript to ring, vibrate, determine position, etc.

There are tutorials for how to make an application for every phone operating system, and they are pretty understandable for beginners. However, since you use joomla, your code has to run on a php server. (The tutorial covers only how to embed local html files in your app).

There are some tutorials out there that cover the use of phonegap with 'existing' websites. Google for it.

In the future, you might want to have a look at jquery mobile, there is an interface builder on their site http://jquerymobile.com/ and it is designed to look good on every device. You can use their themeroller and some additional css to achieve quite a nice app.

Answer (score 0):

Suresh, because it will be important that your users interact with your server where your Joomla installation is hosted, it will be most feasible for you to create separate CSS stylings for your website that will be mobile specific.

Because Joomla has a user community, it is likely that plugins or templates have been written that can help speed this process up.  Here's an extension that accomplishes some of what you're looking for, in-so-far as it will allow users on mobile phones to interact with your website via a browser in a comfortable way.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/mobile/mobile-display/11722

Answer (score 0):

Humm joomla is not a good bet for mobile web apps. Even with adapted css and layouts, If you have a lot of extensions, some might break in mobile view.

I would build a a web app from scratch (using jquery mobile, that as a good cross platform support) and get the data from the original website. It might take a while longer, but the experience for your users will surely be better.

EDIT:

From what I gathered from your comments, it seems you want a landing page where people can download a "game" to their mobile phones, is that right? Please explain exactly what you want to accomplish so we might help you.

Comment: so we can't convert the existing php web application to mobile application, am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Mobile Joomla? It's a great extension that would be an easy first step to getting your site mobile-friendly.

"Mobile Joomla!® is the best way to mobilize your Joomla! site, displaying beautifully on iPhone, iPad, Android, Windows Phone and all other phones."

http://www.mobilejoomla.com/

Comment: Thanks, jnunn. am not asking about vision problem. peoples download the game software from internet like that the user need to download my application from my webpage, then they  need to install their mobile.

Answer (score 0):

for converting the existing web application to mobile application,you have to create web services of the web application and return the data in XML or json format.at the end of mobile development like on  android plateform you have to parse those data on simulator,and this way you can test the application and use in mobile.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Harshal, is it possible for php?